# RevenueCat - UpgradeInfo not working on Android with Flutter

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I’m testing in Android emulator with Play Store access using a testing account so no actual money is being charged. I am able to purchase products and packages, but not able to test changing packages using the [UpgradeInfo docs](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/managing-subscriptions#android). What could the issue be with Play Store or is there some other configuration I need to make somewhere?

When I select the package to change to I see the following, which all looks correct in my logs. The SKU is found and the [Flutter purchases_flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter) is clearly showing everything good to go at this point.

```
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(25398): ℹ️ Vending Offerings from cache
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(25398):  Product change started:  com.revenuecat.purchases.models.ProductDetails@1e0bf2c4  - offering: packages UpgradeInfo: UpgradeInfo(oldSku=package_3.99_monthly, prorationMode=1)
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(25398): ℹ️ Querying Purchase with package_3.99_monthly and type SUBS
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(25398): ℹ️ Checking if cache is stale AppInBackground false
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(25398):  Found existing purchase for SKU: package_3.99_monthly
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(25398):  Moving from old SKU package_3.99_monthly to sku package_39.95_yearly
```

**However, I then see this on the screen:**

[image]

**And then in the logs after clicking OK:**

```
W/ProxyBillingActivity(25398): Activity finished with resultCode 0 and billing's responseCode: 2
W/BillingHelper(25398): Couldn't find purchase lists, trying to find single data.
W/BillingHelper(25398): Received a bad purchase data.
W/BillingHelper(25398): Couldn't find single purchase data as well.
W/BillingHelper(25398): Couldn't find purchase lists, trying to find single data.
W/BillingHelper(25398): Received a bad purchase data.
W/BillingHelper(25398): Couldn't find single purchase data as well.
E/[Purchases] - ERROR(25398): ‼️ BillingWrapper purchases failed to update: DebugMessage: . ErrorCode: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.null
E/[Purchases] - ERROR(25398): ‼️ There was a problem with the Play Store.
I/flutter (25398): PlatformException(2, There was a problem with the Play Store., {code: 2, message: There was a problem with the Play Store., readableErrorCode: StoreProblemError, readable_error_code: StoreProblemError, underlyingErrorMessage: Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: . ErrorCode: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE., userCancelled: false}, null)
```

**Flutter code:**

```dart
await Purchases.purchasePackage(
  myProductList[index],
  upgradeInfo: UpgradeInfo(
    subscriptionTypeString ==
            monthlySubscriptionString
        ? yearlySubscriptionSKU
        : monthlySubscriptionSKU,
    prorationMode: ProrationMode
        .immediateWithTimeProration,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Have you tried other proration modes? Do you get the same result?

Comment: RevenueCat currently only supports IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION. Without any code changes this suddenly started working. Not sure why...